# How to get specific button and edit its text from a row in custom adapter belonging to ListView in Android

Tags: android, listview, android-arrayadapter

I have created my own adapter of a ListView in Android based on this from tutorial taken from: https://looksok.wordpress.com/2012/11/03/android-custom-listview-tutorial/

In this adapter, I have a specific row for each student, where I show his statistics. Each row has some buttons describing some information about student.

The buttons show correct information about the student, but when I want to copy value from "predicted grade" button to "final grade" button by clicking "copy grade" button, adapter copies grade in the last (or first) row displaying on the screen. It depends on direction of currently scrolled list view (scrolling down causes copying grade in the last row displayed on screen, scrolling up causes copying grade in the first row displayed on screen).

I could not find a proper solution about changing values of components which do not parametrize the adapter.

Here is my code:

```
public class SummaryDetStudentsAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<Student> {

private List<Student> items;
private int layoutResourceId;
private Context context;
private AtomSummaryGenStudensHolder holder = null;
private LessonsDetailedManagementWindow parent;
private MySQLiteHelper db;
private View row;
private boolean isLaboratory;

public SummaryDetStudentsAdapter(Context context, int layoutResourceId, List<Student> items) {
    super(context, layoutResourceId, items);
    this.layoutResourceId = layoutResourceId;
    this.context = context;
    this.items = items;
    parent = (LessonsDetailedManagementWindow) context;
    db = parent.getDatabase();
}

@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    row = convertView;
    LayoutInflater inflater = ((Activity) context).getLayoutInflater();
    row = inflater.inflate(layoutResourceId, parent, false);

    holder = new AtomSummaryGenStudensHolder();
    holder.setStudent(items.get(position));
    holder.setPresenceCount((Button) row.findViewById(R.id.btn_presence));
    holder.setAbsentCount((Button) row.findViewById(R.id.btn_absence));
    holder.setTotalPts((Button) row.findViewById(R.id.btn_total_pts));
    holder.setStudentHeader((TextView) row.findViewById(R.id.tv_student_header));
    holder.setTotalActPts((Button) row.findViewById(R.id.btn_total_activity_pts));
    holder.setPerc((Button) row.findViewById(R.id.btn_percent));
    holder.setPredictedGrade((Button) row.findViewById(R.id.btn_predicted_grade));
    holder.setFinalGrade((Button) row.findViewById(R.id.btn_final_grade));
    holder.setCopyGrade((ImageButton) row.findViewById(R.id.btn_copy_grade));

    holder.getPresenceCount().setTag(holder.getStudent());
    holder.getAbsentCount().setTag(holder.getStudent());
    holder.getTotalPts().setTag(holder.getStudent());
    holder.getStudentHeader().setTag(holder.getStudent());
    holder.getTotalActPts().setTag(holder.getStudent());
    holder.getPerc().setTag(holder.getStudent());
    holder.getPredictedGrade().setTag(holder.getStudent());
    holder.getFinalGrade().setTag(holder.getStudent());
    holder.getCopyGrade().setTag(holder.getStudent());

    handleCourseForm();
    row.setTag(holder);
    setupItem(items.get(position));
    prepareButtons();
    return row;
}

protected void handleCourseForm()
{
    if(!this.parent.getGroup().getCourse().getCourseForm().equals(CourseForm.laboratory))
    {
        isLaboratory = false;
        holder.getTotalPts().setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
        holder.getPerc().setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
        holder.getPredictedGrade().setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
    }
    else
    {
        isLaboratory = true;
    }
}

protected void setupItem(Student student)
{
    StudentStatistics ss = parent.getStudentStatistics(student);
    holder.getStudentHeader().setText(TextRepresentationGetter.getStudentRepresentation(student));
    holder.getPresenceCount().setText(ss.getPresenceCount()+"");
    holder.getAbsentCount().setText(ss.getAbsenceCount()+"");
    holder.getTotalActPts().setText(String.format("%.1f",ss.getTotalActivityPoints()));
    if(isLaboratory) {
        holder.getTotalPts().setText(String.format("%.1f", ss.getTotalPoints()));
        int totalPts = parent.getTotalPoints();
        double perc = totalPts == 0 ? 0 : new BigDecimal(ss.getTotalPoints()).divide(new BigDecimal(totalPts),4, RoundingMode.HALF_UP).doubleValue()*100;
        holder.getPerc().setText(String.format("%.2f",perc));
        double grade = parent.getGradeFromPercent(perc);
        holder.getPredictedGrade().setText(totalPts == 0 || (int) grade == 0 ? getContext().getText(R.string.not_available) : String.valueOf(grade));
    }
}

private void prepareButtons()
{
    final ImageButton copyGrade = holder.getCopyGrade();
    copyGrade.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Student s = (Student) v.getTag();
            copyPredictedGradeToFinalGrade(s);
        }
    });
}

private void copyPredictedGradeToFinalGrade(Student s)
{
    Button predictedGrade = holder.getPredictedGrade(); // it takes first or last button displayed on screen
    Button finalGrade = holder.getFinalGrade(); // it should take the button from a row, where the copyGrade button was clicked
    double grade = Double.parseDouble(String.valueOf(predictedGrade.getText()));
    finalGrade.setText(String.valueOf(grade));
}
```

}

```
public class AtomSummaryGenStudensHolder {
private Student student;
private TextView student_header;
private Button presenceCount;
private Button absentCount;
private Button totalActPts;
private Button totalPts;
private Button perc;
private Button predictedGrade;
private Button finalGrade;
private ImageButton copyGrade;


public Student getStudent() {
    return student;
}

public void setStudent(Student student) {
    this.student = student;
}

public Button getPresenceCount() {
    return presenceCount;
}

public void setPresenceCount(Button presenceCount) {
    this.presenceCount = presenceCount;
}

public Button getAbsentCount() {
    return absentCount;
}

public void setAbsentCount(Button absentCount) {
    this.absentCount = absentCount;
}

public Button getTotalActPts() {
    return totalActPts;
}

public void setTotalActPts(Button totalActPts) {
    this.totalActPts = totalActPts;
}

public Button getTotalPts() {
    return totalPts;
}

public void setTotalPts(Button totalPts) {
    this.totalPts = totalPts;
}

public TextView getStudentHeader() {
    return student_header;
}

public void setStudentHeader(TextView student_header) {
    this.student_header = student_header;
}

public Button getPerc() {
    return perc;
}

public void setPerc(Button perc) {
    this.perc = perc;
}

public Button getPredictedGrade() {
    return predictedGrade;
}

public void setPredictedGrade(Button predictedGrade) {
    this.predictedGrade = predictedGrade;
}

public Button getFinalGrade() {
    return finalGrade;
}

public void setFinalGrade(Button finalGrade) {
    this.finalGrade = finalGrade;
}

public ImageButton getCopyGrade() {
    return copyGrade;
}

public void setCopyGrade(ImageButton copyGrade) {
    this.copyGrade = copyGrade;
}
```

}

Row layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">


<TextView
    android:id="@+id/tv_student_header"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textColor="#000000"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    android:textSize="@dimen/text_size_medium"
    />


<Button
    android:id="@+id/btn_presence"
    android:layout_width="@dimen/bulk_data_det_button_size_smaller"
    android:layout_height="@dimen/bulk_data_det_button_size"
    android:background="#80009688"
    android:textColor="#ffffff"
    android:text="@string/attendance_absent_acronym"
    android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/btn_absence"
    android:minWidth="@dimen/bulk_data_det_button_size"
    />


<Button
    android:id="@+id/btn_absence"
    android:layout_width="@dimen/bulk_data_det_button_size_smaller"
    android:layout_height="@dimen/bulk_data_det_button_size"
    android:background="#80ff6666"
    android:textColor="#ffffff"
    android:text="@string/attendance_absent_acronym"
    android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/btn_total_activity_pts"
    android:minWidth="@dimen/bulk_data_det_button_size"
    />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/btn_total_activity_pts"
    android:layout_width="@dimen/bulk_data_det_button_size_smaller"
    android:layout_height="@dimen/bulk_data_det_button_size"
    android:textColor="#000000"
    android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/btn_total_pts"
    android:text="0"
    android:background="#8000bdbd"
    />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/btn_total_pts"
    android:layout_width="@dimen/bulk_data_button_size"
    android:layout_height="@dimen/bulk_data_det_button_size"
    android:textColor="#000000"
    android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/btn_percent"
    android:text="0"
    android:background="#80bdbd00"
    />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/btn_percent"
    android:layout_width="@dimen/bulk_data_button_size"
    android:layout_height="@dimen/bulk_data_det_button_size"
    android:background="#80009688"
    android:textColor="#ffffff"
    android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/btn_predicted_grade"
    android:minWidth="@dimen/bulk_data_det_button_size"
    />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/btn_predicted_grade"
    android:layout_width="@dimen/bulk_data_det_button_size_smaller"
    android:layout_height="@dimen/bulk_data_det_button_size"
    android:background="#8000bdbd"
    android:textColor="#ffffff"
    android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/btn_final_grade"
    android:minWidth="@dimen/bulk_data_det_button_size"
    />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/btn_final_grade"
    android:layout_width="@dimen/bulk_data_det_button_size"
    android:layout_height="@dimen/bulk_data_det_button_size"
    android:background="#80bdbd00"
    android:textColor="#ffffff"
    android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/btn_copy_grade"
    android:minWidth="@dimen/bulk_data_det_button_size"
    />

<ImageButton
    android:id="@+id/btn_copy_grade"
    android:layout_width="@dimen/bulk_data_det_button_size_smaller"
    android:layout_height="@dimen/bulk_data_det_button_size"
    android:textColor="#ffffff"
    android:background="#eeeeee"
    android:scaleType="fitXY"
    android:src="@drawable/check"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:minWidth="@dimen/bulk_data_det_button_size"
    />



</RelativeLayout>
```

I want to change the values of buttons in method prepareButtons (where is the listener of a copyButton) and method copyPredictedGradeToFinalGrade(). It does not work for me. I have tried to get them by 'getTag()' method and casting it later to Button class, but the compiler said everytime that is not a Student class, but not a view.

[image: Screen of list view with custom adapter]

By clicking on a check (number 1 on screen) I want to copy content of button in POC column to KOC column, but there is copied content of button in POC column to KOC column seen in number 2. I have no idea how I can achieve that (I could only operate properly on class Student).

How can I fix this problem? How can I make my code to copy the values in a row, where the image button of check is clicked? I would be grateful for any clue for solving my problem.

Proposals of anwsers dont work for me, because after scrolling up/down, newly elements have listeners of these from top of these displayed on the screen.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Also show row layout xml

Comment: I have just added it

Comment: I strongly suggest you convert your code (or find another tutorial) to RecyclerView. Note that tutorial you are using is 3 years old - this is a lot of time in current android situation. Also recyclerview has built-in methods to efficiently update ui when data changes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problem is here, remove this line:

```
private AtomSummaryGenStudensHolder holder = null;
```

Your functions prepareButtons and copyPredictedGradeToFinalGrade when called use current holder value. After all getView calls this is the last shown view holder value. 
First of all to correctly use ViewHolder pattern your should do something like this:

```
@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    AtomSummaryGenStudensHolder holder;
    row = convertView;
    if (row == null || row .getTag() == null) {
        holder = new AtomSummaryGenStudensHolder();
        row = inflater.inflate(layoutResourceId, parent, false);
    ...

        row .setTag(holder);
    } else {
        holder = (AtomSummaryGenStudensHolder) row.getTag();
    }
```

Then your should pass holder to your functions

```
handleCourseForm(holder );
...
prepareButtons(holder );
```

And you should change all functions where holder is used

```
private void prepareButtons(AtomSummaryGenStudensHolder holder)
{
    final ImageButton copyGrade = holder.getCopyGrade();
    copyGrade.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Student s = (Student) v.getTag();
            copyPredictedGradeToFinalGrade(s, holder);
        }
    });
}

private void copyPredictedGradeToFinalGrade(Student s, AtomSummaryGenStudensHolder holder)
{
    Button predictedGrade = holder.getPredictedGrade(); // it takes first or last button displayed on screen
    Button finalGrade = holder.getFinalGrade(); // it should take the button from a row, where the copyGrade button was clicked
    double grade = Double.parseDouble(String.valueOf(predictedGrade.getText()));
    finalGrade.setText(String.valueOf(grade));
}
```

Comment: I have still the same problem. Changing values works okay, but the first and the last element is filled with random data when i am scrolling list view up and down. If you knew what it could be I would be grateful for help

Comment: If you talk about finalGrade text, try to clear it every time before reuse - holder.getFinalGrade().setText("'); If problem is not only in this field, please describe more details.

Comment: The problem is in list containing more elements than screen's height. When I want to click on button after scrolling, the listener invokes one of n-first elements of the list. I can not change anything. This is the main problem, the less problem is as you wrote writing values to more than one button.

Answer (score 1):

> How can I make my code to copy the values in a row, where the image
>   button of check is clicked?

Do it as use View of `onClick` method to access other views from same layout. change `copyPredictedGradeToFinalGrade` as:

```
private void copyPredictedGradeToFinalGrade(Student s, RelativeLayout view)
{
    Button predictedGrade = (Button)view.findViewById(R.id.btn_predicted_grade);  
    Button finalGrade = = (Button)view.findViewById(R.id.btn_final_grade); 
    double grade = Double.parseDouble(String.valueOf(predictedGrade.getText()));
    finalGrade.setText(String.valueOf(grade));
}
```

and call `copyPredictedGradeToFinalGrade` by passing View as :

```
@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
 Student s = (Student) v.getTag();
 RelativeLayout relativeLayout=(RelativeLayout)view.getParent();
 copyPredictedGradeToFinalGrade(s,relativeLayout);
}
```